# Umbraco 8: Fetch image from URL in javascript and assign result to FileUpload control in form

Tags: javascript, file-upload, umbraco, umbraco8

**Background:**

In my `DocumentType` I have added a `FileUpload`.  I am requesting JSON from an API, which returns some meta data, including the url of an image.

I would like then fetch that image (I know how to do that already) and set it as the content of the `FileUpload`, that way it can be saved onto my document object in Umbraco.

**Q) How to I programatically (in JS) set the content of the `FileUpload` in an Umbraco 8 content form?**

e.g.

[image]

Comment: So you basically want to save an image file to the field `FileUpload` of `document type` from a fetched Image, do you have access to the `Image.Stream` in your `SurfaceController`?